# How can I animate my Google Map to pan to the right endlessly and seamlessly?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have implemented a map using Snazzy Maps and the google maps API.
It can be found on my website here: http://www.welcomehomemusic.net.

I noticed while inspecting map element and clicking and dragging right on the map it is updating this css property on a div.

The property is transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -690, 0);
I would like to animate that 5th value smoothly by having it increase endlessly.

My first thought would be to use css animations and keyframes or maybe by using Javascript somehow.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Having had a quick look at your site there are no iframes involved so there should be nothing stopping you from animating the position using CSS. This article should get you going: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: How would you go about endlessly increasing that 5th value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by using css animations. I set the width of my map to 6000px and used css transforms to move it. Here's what I did.

`@keyframes mapSlide {
    0%  { transform: translateX(-100vw); }
    50% { transform: translateX(0px); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100vw); }
}`

```
#aristMap {
    height:300px;
    width:6000px;
    z-index:8;
    animation: mapSlide 90s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the API docs:

> > `panBy(x:number, y:number)`
> >
> > Changes the center of the map by the given distance in pixels. If the distance is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Note that the map coordinate system increases from west to east (for x values) and north to south (for y values).
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#methods

Then it's as easy as:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
function infiniPan() {
    map.panBy(-0.2, 0);
    setTimeout(infiniPan, 100);
}
infiniPan();
```

I should point out it's going to eat some cpu.